# Make a timer in swing

Tags: java, swing, timer

For this game I'm making for java class, I want a timer display in the corner that counts up from `0`

I made a variable that represents seconds, which ==> double s =0;

My idea was that using a `Timer` object where I could increment the variable every second and use the `repaint()` method on the string

However, I misinterpreted how the timer object works, and after the delay it counts up rapidly to infinity. I have no idea what to do now. A hint would be appreciated.

Here is my code,thanks for any help:

```
 int delay = 5000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        s=(int)s+1;


    }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
  String t = "" + s;
g.drawString(t, 100, 100);
repaint();
```

Comment: Swing Timer missing repaint() in ActionListener, [more read in Oracle Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/index.html), here is daily asked 5-10 questions about paintComponent

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: (you might have to change it for your needs)

```
boolean temp=true;
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
while(temp){

    float time = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/ 10000000.000f;

    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try doing is implementing the Runnable interface and then starting a new Thread of the class that you are using to draw your Components. Since Thread implements the Runnable interface, you will be able to create a new point of execution in the program where you can call a delay with Thread.sleep() before repainting your components. Here is an example of what you should try doing:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(ClassNameHere);
    thread.start();
```

If you are interested in trying this out, more information can be found on the API on [Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and on the [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface.